# nestjs Integrated golevelup/rabbitmq in external library

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

all is in my title,
i want to create an private external package in nestjs.
and i would to integrate the lib golevelup/rabbitmq for reuse it on my different projects.

I install library on my package, i configure the "main" module with rabbitmqmodule, i write default values for reduce dependencies and to integrate module rabbitmq it step by step.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RabbitMQModule.forRootAsync(RabbitMQModule, {
      useFactory: () => {        
        return {
          exchanges: [{ name: "rabname", type: "rabtype" }],
          uri: `amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@localhost:5672`,
          connectionInitOptions: { wait: false },
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [R],
})
export class PersoRabbitModule extends ConfigurableModuleClass {}
```

But, when i create a dependency in an other project, i have an error of internal package rabbitmq dependancy like that:

```
Error   13/03/2023, 17:22:47 \[ExceptionHandler\] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RabbitMQModule (DiscoveryService, ?, RabbitRpcParamsFactory, AmqpConnectionManager). Please make sure that the argument ExternalContextCreator at index \[1\] is available in the RabbitMQModule context.

Potential solutions:

- If ExternalContextCreator is a provider, is it part of the current RabbitMQModule?
- If ExternalContextCreator is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RabbitMQModule?
  @Module({
  imports: \[ /\* the Module containing ExternalContextCreator \*/ \]
  })
```

My code of appmodule on an other project (parameter is for next implementation step) :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PersoRabbitModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => {
        return {
          host: 'http://localhost',
          vhost: '/',
          port: 15672,
          user: 'guest',
          password: 'guest',
          consumerExchange: null,
          identityExchange: null,
        }
      }}),
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Could you help me because i not understand this error.

I already use the golevelup/rabbitmq package in another api.
and it work well, but when it where in an external package, it has a dependencies problem.